# Use IQueryable<AnonymousType> in second join

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a query with multiple joins.
My first query works perfect, but when I want to use this result (IQueryable) in my second join, I get an error. 
How can I use my first result object in my second query?

thanks!

```
ISession session = NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSession(SessionFactoryConfigPath);

IQueryable<Approval> approvals = session.Query<Approval>();
IQueryable<Ticket> tickets = session.Query<Ticket>()
            .Where(t => t.Canceled == null 
                        && t.IsNotified == null);
IQueryable<Notification> notifications = session.Query<Notification>();

var qry = approvals.Join(tickets, 
                            a => a.TicketID, 
                            t => t.ID, 
                            (a, t) => new { Ticket = t, Approval = a });

//here I want to use my IQueryable<Anonymous> object to create my second join.
qry = notifications.Join(qry, 
                        n => n.DatabaseID, 
                        anon => anon.Ticket.DatabaseID, 
                        (n, anon) => 
                            new {Ticket = anon.Ticket, 
                                Approval = anon.Approval, 
                                Notification = n});
```

Comment: "I get an error" - errors tend to contain useful information - even if you don't understand the error, it's a lot easier for us if you give us the actual error message.

Comment: "The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage" is my error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are affecting the result of the second `Join...` to `qry`, they haven't the same type.

Use a different variable:

```
var result = notifications.Join(qry, 
                        n => n.DatabaseID, 
                        anon => anon.Ticket.DatabaseID, 
                        (n, anon) => 
                            new {Ticket = anon.Ticket, 
                                Approval = anon.Approval, 
                                Notification = n});
```

Comment: Hey, this answer is correct, the problem was a type difference between `anon.Ticket.DatabaseID` (int) and `n.DatabaseID` (guid). I still got the error. SO I created a different variable and this works fine! Thanks!